# defaultSession,ProgrammingSession,extendedDiagnosticSession

Tags: protocols, can-bus, canoe

I am not understanding about defaultSession,ProgrammingSession,extendedDiagnosticSession in UDS protocol.
How can we go from one session to another session? please help me.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**default** session = ECU is in normal operation state, but it usualy response only to limited set of diagnostic requests. From this state you can *usually* switch into:

- **extended** session to perform some diagnostic services, to *talk* with ECU (Read/Write values, start/stop routines etc.) Here you expect that ECU give a more or less timely response on your requests. therefore you can also switch between sessions
- **programming** session to flash ECU memory, to update ECU SW. While updating ECU usually do not answer on diagnostic requests. Therefore it's not usual to switch from programming session into extended session or even into default session as this switch is a diagnostic request from tester. At the end of an update ECU can perform some memory checks and it will do a reset. When update was successful it will restart in default session.

There can be also other diagnostic sessions for example: dealer session, OEM session...

Comment: Depends on requirement we should go.?

Answer (score 0):

Where is the problem? Since you are using CANoe, you can simply switch the session with the "Session Control" tool, which is in the ribbon menu "Diagnostics & XCP". For more info take a look at the chapter "Diagnostic Session Control" of the help.

If the ECU is protected you need to configure the seed & key DLL file and configuration. For more info look at "Seed & Key DLL / Security Access".

For an example take a look at the "UDSSystem" demo.

Comment: When I am in programming session can I jump to extended session?